# I want to create arrow shape using CSS -- Please see screenshot

Tags: css

I want to create a Arrow shape CSS like this one

[Screenshot](http://prntscr.com/7l3rza)

I want to create a next and previous post button like this... please help

Comment: Please see: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Comment: Please post the code you have tried so far, and read the advice on [how to write a good question on StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 2):

Use pseudo element and CSS triangle :

```css
.arrow-right,
.arrow-left {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 20px;
  padding: 0 6px;
  color: white;
  background-color: #A5A5A5;
}
.arrow-right::after,
.arrow-left::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-style: solid;
}
.arrow-right::after {
  right: -10px;
  border-color: transparent transparent transparent #A5A5A5;
  border-width: 10px 0 10px 10px;
}
.arrow-left::after {
  left: -10px;
  border-color: transparent #A5A5A5 transparent transparent;
  border-width: 10px 10px 10px 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="arrow-right">Lorem</div>
<br>
<div class="arrow-left">Lorem</div>
```

Comment: Consider, this arrow is for the next post
What about the Previous post Arrow... I mean the for Next the blend is on right side... But for previous the BLEND is must be on left side...

Can you help me to create a Arrow for previous post

Comment: Add `transform: rotate(180deg);` and change `right: -10px;` by `left: -10px;` in the `.arrow::after` selector to create the "previous button"

Comment: Exactly what @Mark said :) Or instead of using rotate, you can point the triangle towards left. I edit the fiddle